# support:clickToDial in console Click to Dial Disabled

Tags: visualforce, console, cti

I have a Visualforce page that uses `<support:clickToDial>`. When a user is in Service Console, click to dial is disabled. Click to dial works in standard Salesforce salesforce pages and on my Visualforce page when not in console. It also works if I exit the CTI adaptor and reopen it while console is open with the page up. What might be a solution?

I am including the javascript.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/24.0/integration.js"/>
```

Update: looks like it is something very specific about the page (which is a mess anyways). I can't replicate if I start from a fresh page. Looks like I'll start from scratch on the page and write it the way it should have been written to start...

Update 2: I found the culprit. It appears to be because I have a partial rerender on the page that renders a table of phone numbers based on data the user enters in an input box. This only seems to be an issue when the page is the main tab in console. It works everywhere else. I'll try to get some cleaned up demo code. Right now it is a bit of a mess. I think the Javascript to enable clicktodial only runs on page load or CTI adaptor load and not when a section rerenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this issue. When my page loads, there are no phone numbers on the page. Phone numbers only display after an account is selected. The display is performed with a partial page rerender. If I put a phone number on the page using `<support:clickToDial>` that is visible when the page loads, than all subsequent rerenders have the click to dial link enabled. I suspect this is due to Salesforce only loading some JavaScript at page load if there are phone numbers that use click to dial.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the latest version of the library ? I know it works since 29 but not sure about 24.

```
 <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/32.0/integration.js"/>
```

Comment: I tried up to version 32. Doesn't work with any.